# (Django - Python) Hidden Input Request to views.py

Tags: python, django, input, request, hidden

I have to create a site with auctions and I have an homepage which shows all the auctions active...

I want to redirect users to auctions details clicking on relative button but I have some problems with the hidden input request because it doesn't report the hidden value to my function ( def bid (request, auction) ) but I see it on the url bar after the csrfmiddlewaretoken (id=1), can you help me? (I have tried also with POST request...)

These are my codes:

- views.py

> ```
>  def home(request):
>
>  auctions = Auction.objects.filter(status=True)
>
>  form = detailForm(request.GET or None)
>
>  if request.method == "GET":
>
>      id = request.GET.get("id")
>
>      if form.is_valid():
>
>          [bid(request,auction) for auction in auctions if auction.id==id]
>
>      else:
>
>          form = detailForm()
>
>  return render(request, "index.html", {"auctions":auctions, "form":form})
> ```

> ```
> def bid(request, auction):
>
> user = request.user
>
> form = bidForm(request.POST)
>
> if request.method == "POST":
>
>     bid = request.POST.get("endPrice")
>
>     if form.is_valid():
>
>         if bid > auction.startPrice:
>
>             auctionUpdate=form.save(commit=False)
>             auctionUpdate.endPrice=bid
>             auctionUpdate.winner=user
>             auctionUpdate.save()
>
>         else:
>
>             messages.warning(request, "Devi puntare una cifra superiore a quella vincente!")
>     else:
>
>         form = bidForm()
>
> return render(request, "bid.html", {"form":form})
> ```

- forms.py

> ```
> class detailForm(forms.ModelForm):
>
> class Meta:
>     model = Auction
>     fields = ("id",)
> ```

- index.html

  ```
  {% for auction in auctions %}
  <--! I put all the informations about auctions -->
  <form method="GET">
  {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{auction.id}}>
     <input type="submit">
  {% endfor %}
  </form>
  ```

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, so basically we have a list of auctions, and when a user clicks on a related button of an auction, the user will be redirected to another page.

In this model, you need to think about 2 views and 2 templates to handle them.
A `ListView` to list all your actions and a `DetailView` to handle the detail page of each auction. So you will have a `home.html` for your `ListView` and a `bid.html` for your auction detail.

I think the form submission should be implemented in your detail view (in your code the `bid` function), and the detail view should render a page with the `bid.html` template.

In your `home.html` you may want to just leave a link of each auction like:

```html
{% for auction in auctions %}

<a type='button' href="{{ auction.get_absolute_url }}">{{ auction.name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

You need to add this `get_absolute_url` method in your `Auction` model, for example:

```py
# models.py
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("auction-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Also in your routing:

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', home, name='home'),
    path('/auctions/<int:pk>/', bid, name='auction-detail'),
]
```

You need to pass `auction` to your context variable in your `bid` function as well, in order to refer to it in your template.

```py
def bid (request, auction_id):
    auction = Auction.objects.get_object_or_404(id=auction_id)
    # ...
    context = {'form': form, 'auction': auction}
    return render(request, "bid.html", context)
```

And finally in your detail view template (`bid.html`), use the form to submit:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value={{auction.id}}>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Another suggestion is that try to use **Class Based View** such as `ListView` and `DetailView` in this case, which will handler your problem much easier. Check [this article](https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-class-based-views-vs-function-based-view-e74b47b2e41b) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Yes, that's the idea, I will try your solution and I let you know about ^^

Comment: Thanks, I've done some changes but your help was essential! ;)